# Asp validators across user child controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I have  simple web form. It has quite a few custom text boxes(basically the asp text box with some extra properties wrapped inside a user control). At the end of the page there is another user control that has submit button in it.

As you can see the submit button is inside a user control. I want to use asp required field validator on one of the text boxes. I have exposed the CauseValidation, ValidationGroup property on all user controls (on the button in submit child control and the custom text boxes). But the validation doesn't work.

I can not change how this so called framework work. Submit will have to stay inside a user control and I will have to use these custom text boxes.

My question is more around, is there a limitation around asp standard validators, where they can or can not be used. Like the scenario here, where all controls to be validated don't sit on the form directly, but are inside other user controls. Text box is inside a user control, validator directly sits on the form, submit button that will trigger validation is in another user control.

How do you debug to check whether or not the validator is actually being fired?

Comment: what is the problem? validation is not working in child control ?

Comment: Apologies if I was not clear enough. Validator is not inside the child control. Validator is on the main form and the control to be validated in inside child control. I can make it work some how by changing and moving controls. My question is, is it possible to validate a TextBox inside a child control on click of a button that is in another child control and the validator itself is on the main form.

Comment: You can use custom validator and implement the client-side and server-side logic yourself. If you post your sample code, I could help more

Comment: I know I can use the custom validator, that is not the issue. My question is more around, can a validator on the main form validate an asp control inside a custom control. There is no reason it shouldn't. I have solved my problem by putting the validator inside the custom control itself. But if I don't have the source of the custom control, but everything in the custom control is exposed through public properties, how do I make the standard asp validator work in that case.